# React native Challenging task

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jquery-mobile, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner of both **React** and **React native**, and I had search along a couple of site with the library to create left tab, and fortunately I found the only one here in this link which is 90% as my expectations:

https://github.com/DaKaZ/react-native-vertical-tab-view

However it doesn't really work with my platform. My visual studio code cannot accept this piece of thing in the code.

> Element<*>

And if i'm not mistaken, the article is defining the orientation of the phone to achieve that. But I don't need any orientation by the way. Can any professional  of React native explains me what does that symbol above means? and where can i find good example to practice step by step on how to produce the outcome as shown in the site?

Your advise is very much appreciated!

Comment: That is not `Javascript`. That's an Element that brings everything inside him, in `TypeScript`. Check their docs to find out more: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html

Answer (score 0):

That is React + Flow 
You can get some explanation here:
https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4130